# How do I find the area in which the camera field of view encompasses?

Tags: c#, vector, unity-game-engine

Given the camera's perspective is a pyramid shape, how do find the area in which this pyramid encompasses?

Comment: Do you really need to know that exact area or do you just want to know if a object is inside or outside of that area. Those are two very different problems with different solutions.

Comment: it is called the ***frustrum*** of the camera

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I have a database of 150,000 objects and I want to populate the universe with any of the objects that reside within the frustrum

Comment: @user1861013 Out of curosity, are you [munter on the Occulus forums](https://forums.oculus.com/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=29431)? (and if you are not, perhaps using his solution may help you solve your X in the [XY problem you asked us about](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Comment: @ScottChamberlain No this isn't me, but my project sounds very similar!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple script that make use of camera viewport instead of screen. It is a more general approach :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MyCameraUtilityScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Vector3> GetCameraFrustrumCorners()
    {
        List<Vector3> corners = new List<Vector3>(8); // 8 corners

        Camera c = GetComponent<Camera>();

        // corners counterclockwise at near clip plane
        corners.Add(c.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, c.nearClipPlane))); // bottom-left
        corners.Add(c.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(1.0f, 0.0f, c.nearClipPlane))); // bottom-right
        corners.Add(c.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, c.nearClipPlane))); // top-right
        corners.Add(c.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, c.nearClipPlane))); // top-left

        // corners counterclockwise at far clip plane
        corners.Add(c.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, c.farClipPlane))); // bottom-left
        corners.Add(c.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(1.0f, 0.0f, c.farClipPlane))); // bottom-right
        corners.Add(c.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, c.farClipPlane))); // top-right
        corners.Add(c.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, c.farClipPlane))); // top-left

        return corners;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I was doing it wrong in my answer, I just deleted it and upvoted yours instead.